# Why can't I perform a simple division in haskell?

Tags: haskell

This code:

```
division :: Double -> Int -> Double
division x k = x / k
```

gives me:

```
Prelude> :l main
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, interpreted )

main.hs:2:20: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the second argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘k’
      In the expression: x / k
      In an equation for ‘division’: division x k = x / k
```

I'm new to haskell, so could you please explain what the issue here is?

Comment: Many programming languages allow "numeric promotions", automatically converting numeric data types according to some rules, e.g. integers can be turned into floating point values. Haskell does not follow this path: no numeric conversion is done automatically, and operations like `+` or `/` require operands having the same type. One then has to manually convert values, when needed, using e.g. `fromIntegral`. (However, numeric literals like `5` are always taken at the right type: `5+x` will work, no promotion needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the first parameter is a `Double` and the second an `Int`. The [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) requires that the two operands and the result all have the same type and are members of the `Fractional` type: the two operands are different here, and `Int` is of course not a member of the `Fractional` typeclass.

You can convert the `Int` to a `Double` first, with [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral):

```
division :: Double -> Int -> Double
division x k = x / fromIntegral k
```